# input type checkbox size not working

Tags: html, css

ie browser has a checkbox alignment problem actully ie take default size of checkbox which is width 20px and height 20px but other browser does not take this property so i want to change the size of input box

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style >

*{margin:0px; height:0}
.jitu {width:40px; height:40px;}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<input type="checkbox" class="jitu" size="10" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're only looking for cross browser consistency, take a peek at Formalize.me http://formalize.me/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the check box in the container and give the height/width to that contianer..

```
*{margin:0px; height:0}
.jitu {width:40px; height:40px;}


<div class="jitu">
<input type="checkbox"  size="10" />
</div>
```

Once you've set the height and width of the container -- you can place the checkbox where ever you want withing the container.. with margin for the checkbox..

Comment: i want of increase the size of checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Clearly **[Quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input)**

**size**

> The initial size of the control. This value is in pixels unless the
>   value of the type attribute is text or password, in which case, it is
>   an integer number of characters. Starting in HTML5, this attribute
>   applies only when the type attribute is set to ***text, search, tel, url,email, or password;***
>   otherwise it is ignored. In addition, the size
>   must be greater than zero. If you don't specify a size, a default
>   value of 20 is used.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to change the size of input box

You have misunderstood what the `size` attribute specifies for an `input`. It is not a specifier of physical length; it is a specifier of how many *characters of input data* is shown on the control.

From the [HTML specification for the `size` attribute for `input`](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-size-attribute):

> The `size` attribute gives the number of characters that, in a visual rendering, the user agent is to allow the user to see while editing the element's value.

The [`checkbox` input type](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/checkbox) does not recognise a `size` specification, because the data doesn't have different sizes.

To change the *appearance* of the element, you need to alter its `style` using CSS.